# Is there a way to show the probability within hue category in Seaborn histogram

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, histogram

For example, I have a dataframe:

```
data = {'1': [1, 1, 2,2,2,2,2, 3,2.5,2.5,1.5,2,2.5,2, 2, 3,1.5,2],
       '2': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0, 0,0,0],
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data).T
df
```

[image: df]

I would like to draw a histogram in Seaborn,

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.histplot(data=df, x="1", hue='2',stat='probability')
```

[image: histogram]

Due to class 0 having few records, the bar is quite low (I want it's max height the same as class 1) even if I add a "stat" parameter of 'probability'.

It's because it's the "probability" out of **total**, is there another kind of "probability" exactly out of the **hue category** (0 and 1 here)?

Comment: I think you want `common_norm=False`.

Comment: Thank you mwaskom, ```common_norm=False``` worked.

Answer (score 3):

As @mwaskom mentioned, this can be achieved combining `stat='probability'` and `common_norm=False`:

```py
sns.histplot(data=df, x="1", hue='2',stat='probability', common_norm=False)
```